# Getting proper line breaks in email to sms with php mail()

Tags: php

I am sending emails to sms using php. I am using `@mms.att.net` instead of `@txt.att.net` as it allows me to control the name who the text message is from. `@txt.att.net` uses a random number that cant be changed. Everything sends great however I am having issues getting line breaks to display how I want. I have tried multiple combinations such as `\r\n` `\n\r` `\r` `\n` however am having no luck. They all return the same result except `\n\r` which double spaces. It doesn't help to send the message in `text/html` as the phones sms program wont interpret `<br>` and shows as chars in the body if I was to use it. I have tried. So I am sending in `text/plain` The result I am getting is as follows

```
 Tim Smith

 Time: 6PM

 Location: Somewhere, USA

 Phone: 111-111-1111

 Status: Open
```

And what I am trying to achieve is for it to look like this with no spaces between each line.

```
Tim Smith
Time: 6PM
Location: Somewhere, USA
Phone: 111-111-1111
Status: Open
```

My code for PHP mail() is

```
    $txt  = "Test". "\n".
            "$firstname $lastname\r\n".
            "Time: $JobTime\r\n".
            "Location: $City, $State\r\n".
            "Phone: $Phone\r\n".
            "Status: $JobStatus";

    $to = "1111111111@mms.att.net";
    $subject = "Test Message";
    $txt;
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Test<test@example.com>" . "\r\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers,"-f test@example.com");
```

Might there be a different method to achieve what I want?

Comment: have you tried sending the email to `@txt.att.net` instead of `@mms.att.net`? as per documentation, the `@txt.att.net` is the domain for text based messages.

Comment: @Muhammad yes i have. It returns the same result. The only reason i use `@mms.att.net` is because it allows me to control the display of who the message comes from whereas `@txt.att.net` will return a random number for the from. But both show identical in the body of the message

Comment: Guesstimating again, but I would try just using `\n` alone instead of `\r\n` - some systems might treat both as new line chars.